# Hard-wired Linksys Velop Mesh Bridge Nodes Out Of Range

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, ethernet, mesh-networking

I have 5 x Linksys Velop WHW01v01, all have the latest 1.1.13.202617 firmware.

These are set in bridge mode as my ISP does not allow using any router other than the one they supply. The ISP router has wi-fi disabled.

Until recently, 4 of these were hard wired and 1 was using wi-fi for back channel.

This all worked fine with all 5 nodes showing solid blue lights.

I recently added more ethernet to my house and now all 5 nodes are hard wired.

Now the node connected to the router flashes red (Out of range) and all the other nodes intermittently change between solid blue (Connected to internet) and solid red (No internet).

However, this does not disrupt the internet for our wi-fi devices, all remain connected even when the nodes are solid red.

Any ideas on what is causing this "issue"? - in quotes because it only appears to be the LEDs and not the actual internet affected

Comment: “However, this does not disrupt the internet for our wi-fi devices, all remain connected even when the nodes are solid red.” - That suggests your devices are not actually using Velop devices

Comment: Thats what I thought, but there is no other wifi in the house, and when the nearest node goes red my phone keeps full bars on the wifi icon, suggesting it is still connecting via the nearest node

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried taking the child nodes out one by one, eventually paring it back to just the parent node connected to my router and nothing else

It was still flashing red!

Ended up factory resetting the whole lot

All good now